# How to remove certain items that are not duplicate in 2 lists?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

For example (here's the code I'm working on):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from string import digits
import requests

joke_of_the_day = []
a = []
url_joke_of_the_day = "https://www.womansday.com/life/entertainment/a38635408/corny-jokes/"
page_joke_of_the_day = requests.get(url_joke_of_the_day)
soup_joke_of_the_day = BeautifulSoup(page_joke_of_the_day.content, "html.parser")
content_joke_of_the_day = soup_joke_of_the_day.find("div", class_="article-body-content article-body standard-body-content css-z6i669 ewisyje5")
goodcontents_joke_of_the_day = content_joke_of_the_day.find_all("li")
a.append(goodcontents_joke_of_the_day)
#print(a)

for goodcontent_joke_of_the_day in goodcontents_joke_of_the_day:
  joke_of_the_day1 = goodcontent_joke_of_the_day.find("strong")
  joke_of_the_day2 = str(joke_of_the_day1).replace("<strong>","")
  joke_of_the_day3 = joke_of_the_day2.replace("</strong>","")
  joke_of_the_day4 = joke_of_the_day3.replace("<br>","")
  joke_of_the_day5 = joke_of_the_day4.replace("<br/>","")
  joke_of_the_day.append(joke_of_the_day5)
```

I'm trying to web scrape jokes for a project I'm working on, however the response to the jokes are outside of  . An example:

```
<li>
   ::marker
   <strong> Why did the bay strawberry cry?</strong>
   <br>
   **"His parents were in a jam."**
</li>
```

I was thinking on creating two lists and removing duplicates however that didn't work, here's the code to remove duplicates:

```
for i in a[:]:
  if i in joke_of_the_day:
    a.remove(i)
```

I'm open to any suggestions, I just need the bold-part of the code

Comment: I don't understand. Do you need to get only the responses? Or questions + responses?

Comment: You should be using `joke_of_the_day1.get_text()` to get the question instead of manually stripping the tags.

Comment: I need questions + responses, but with the code above i already got the responses in joke_of_the_day

Answer (score 0):

To get question + responses you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.womansday.com/life/entertainment/a38635408/corny-jokes/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for n, joke in enumerate(soup.select("li:has(strong)"), 1):
    question = joke.strong.text
    response = joke.br.find_next(text=True)

    print(f"Joke nr.{n}")
    print(question)
    print(response)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Joke nr.99
What did the tomato say to the other tomato during a race? 
"Ketchup."
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Joke nr.100
What has four wheels and flies?
A garbage truck.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Joke nr.101
Why didn't the skeleton get a prom date?
He didn't have the guts to ask anyone. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you, but could you also explain the code? I have no idea what happened

Comment: @pythonnoob The key components are: `soup.select("li:has(strong)")` -> selects all `<li>` elements which contain `<strong>` tag. These `<li>` elements contain questions/answers. Then I select question: `joke.strong.text` (text from `<strong>` tag) and answer `joke.br.find_next(text=True)` (next text after the `<br>` tag)

Comment: ohhhh I see, thank you I will play around with it to explore it further.